# What type of terminal pins do radio harnesses use?

Tags: honda, audio, accord, wiring, electronics

Brief backstory: I got a car that was a great deal and the radio is the only thing wrong with it. They told me that while they were swapping out the OEM radio it wouldn't accept the new one and then when they went back to OEM it didn't work either. After close inspection it appears that someone was aggressive with the plug on the car's side and the pins were removed out the back of the radio. I was able to insert 3/5 back in no problem, but 2 of them the wires escaped the pin instead of the pin escaping the harness when it was tugged, so the original pins are worthless.

Question: What type of pins do I need to buy to replace these? The only ones I'm able to find reliably online is Dupont 2.54mm ones. Would those fit?

I have a terminal crimper that I bought for another project and I believe it can crimp these as well. It's a 2015 Honda Accord EX. I would like to buy multiple types of pins for other projects and making my own harnesses I just need to make sure this one is right on the first try to avoid double 18 day shipping.

Obviously I could go to a junkyard and get another harness, but I appreciate things being and looking stock and a new harness would require pulling 2 pins from that and soldering it instead of just crimping what's already there and inserting it like brand new.

Comment: https://racespeconline.com/collections/connector-kits/honda-connectors

Comment: Or https://connectorexperts.com/c-1458515-terminals.html

Comment: Awesome Moab, I think that might be just what I'm looking for.

Comment: So it looks like the radio harness isn't on the list, but I'm sure it's one of those terminals listed on the other site. 25 for 10 is gonna make it unreasonable to get them all, but hopefully that'll help me narrow down my searches using their descriptions.

It may also allow me to match it using my caliper to the pin which netted me no results earlier. Much appreciated.

Comment: Call connectorexperts and talk to them.

Comment: I sent them an email before you even sent that lol. I have high hopes about it so we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Most pins will have a small tag that buts against a ridge in the plastic case.

Find that and adjust it.

Comment: I think maybe I explained that poorly, but there are 3 pins in which just that tab was bent a little bit and I was able to get those to clip back in just fine. The 2 other ones though the pins remained in the harness while the wires crimped to them slipped out. So I'm good on the 3, but need help replacing the pins for the 2 wires where the crimp slipped. I've removed the 2 unattached pins from the housing and am unsure of what type of pin they are.

Comment: @Jdubs with care the crimp can be prised open and the wires re-fitted and crimped. A very rapid solution compared to finding then waiting for parts. Failing that soldering the wires back on works but you have to be neat otherwise they may not fit anymore.

Comment: I gave that a go at first, not expecting much, but I think the crimps were made poorly in the first place (overtightened) which is probably why those wires weren't in tight enough to avoid slipping. Doing it a second time caused a crack in the brass. In hindsight I probably could have annealed it, but oh well.

Soldering is my last ditch solution, but I'd really like to avoid it. After all, soldering is what I'm trying to avoid by not going to the junk yard and getting a new harness then soldering the new wire to the old one.